# How to handle multiipart form-data request in Rest API

Tags: c#, json, rest

My mobile vendors are sending me below request for uploading a file..

```
var client = new RestClient(URL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "52606652-         f26a-e809-0de1-97a6030097eb");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001", "-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-   Disposition: form-data; name``=\"attachement\"; filename=\"[object Object]\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--",   ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Please can anyone tell me how to write code to upload a file in rest API c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the multipart posted data from httpcontext like this:

```
    [HttpPost]  
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadDoc()
    {
        try
        {

            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string file in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files)
                {
                    byte[] postedFile = null;
                    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[file].InputStream))
                    {
                        postedFile = binaryReader.ReadBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[file].ContentLength);

                    }
                    string fileName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys[0];
                }
            }
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

Comment: The Request I am getting is null.. Please suggest